# How to give a no-Administrator user rights to manage IIS?

Tags: iis

The organization policy does not allow normal users be assigned to Administrators group of some Windows Server.
But some of them need rights to manage the IIS service of these server via RDP.
What kind of permission should I give to these users to let them could manage IIS without add them to Administrators group?

All these servers are not in Domain.

Comment: ServerFault.com is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IIS 6, these users must be local administrator if they want to manage IIS.

Comment: Not according to this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/bernard/archive/2005/05/08/46074.aspx